# how to draw arc in js with touch events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

how to draw arc in js with touch events  ?
[image]
like this picture
can't draw anything

I use js bootstrap jquery

```
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
    if (!touch.drawing) return;

    touch.endX = e.touches[0].clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    touch.endY = e.touches[0].clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(touch.endX - touch.startX, 2) + Math.pow(touch.endY - touch.startY, 2));
    var angle = Math.atan2(touch.endY - touch.startY, touch.endX - touch.startX);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(touch.startX, touch.startY, radius, 0, angle, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    touch.startX = touch.endX;
    touch.startY = touch.endY;
});
```

I use this code but not work

Comment: You are drawing `ctx.arc(touch.startX, touch.startY` where are those initialized?